# Binding Custom exception from BAL to ModelState of controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, modelbinders

MY Business service return custom rules exception with dictionary of key/value when some validation error occurred.

For such validation errors i want to handle in my MVC project and bind with ModelState so, those errors will automatically populates in the views.

But since it automatically redirect to error page when any exception occurs. Does it possible to handle error and show on same view ?

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    BusinessService.SomeOperation(model);

    return RedirectToAction("Index"); //success
}
catch(RulesException ex)
{
    foreach(var validationResult in ex.Result)
    {
          ModelState.Add(validationResult.Key, validationResult.Value)
    } //populate modelstate

    return View(model); //redisplay view with errors
}
```

Comment: :), Currently I have used the same way for time being, but is there any way i can bind errors to ModelState ? then things will be per MVC stranded.

Comment: What do you mean in binding errors to ModelState? ModelState.Add does that I think

Comment: yes correct, but i should be able to add it with out wrapping method  call with try catch, instead i want some filter, let say exception filter do that for me automatically.

Comment: and what will happen if  i am using business rules methods through WCF service, still i will be able to use that model state dictionary in business layer and serialize it through WCF to UI layer .